# Cannot Connect to MongoDB Pod via Flask app Pod

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I'm attempting to connect to my MongoDB pod, but I'm failing. Previously, I was just using an online resource to host my MongoDB. Now I want to deploy my DB with Kubernetes. However, I'm having issues connecting to my DB pod via my Flask application and cannot find any examples that are using Minikube or python.

This is how I'm attempting to connect to my pod and populate it:

```
be_host = os.getenv('MONGO-DB_SERVICE_HOST', 'mongo-db')
be_port = os.getenv('MONGO-DB_SERVICE_PORT', '27017')
url = 'http://{}:{}/rba-db'.format(be_host, be_port)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'pymongo_db'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = url

mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/populate_db')
def populate_db():
    patient = mongo.db.patients
    patient.insert({'id': 1, 'fname': 'Jill', 'lname': 'Smith', 'age': '50', 'weight': '63.3', 'conditions': ['Stage 2 Diabetes', 'Cancer', 'Aids']})
    patient.insert({'id': 2, 'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Smith', 'age': '52', 'weight': '86.2', 'conditions': ['Heart Disease', 'Cancer']})
    patient.insert({'id': 3, 'fname': 'Ryan', 'lname': 'Gosling', 'age': '25', 'weight': '75', 'conditions': ['Flu']})
    patient.insert({'id': 4, 'fname': 'Sean', 'lname': 'Winnot', 'age': '21', 'weight': '82', 'conditions': ['Lupis']})
    return "Patients Added."
```

This is my deployment:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo-db
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mongo-db
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 31003
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-db
  labels:
    app: mongo-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-db
        image: mongo:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
```

I have tried:

```
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase"
```

as suggested, but I get the error `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.` when trying to add to my db via /populate_db

I've also tried:

```
mongo = MongoClient("mongodb://mongo:27017/patients")
```

with the same outcome as the latter.

**Edit:**

There was a problem with my docker image not updating correctly

`mongo = MongoClient("mongodb://mongo:27017/patients")`

works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
url = 'http://{}:{}/rba-db'.format(be_host, be_port)
```

`http://` is that right?

```py
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase"
```

As far as I know, `mongo url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase"`

Comment: I tried that earlier but got error `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.`

Comment: this example just sample, try this example
```uri = "mongodb://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(user, password, host, port, db_name)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = uri```